# How do you clear all and then add new items to a Kendo Multiselect in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm making an AJAX call and the response I get back looks like this:

```
[{
  Value: "val1",
  Text: "text1"
}, {
  Value: "val2",
  Text: "text2"
}, {
  Value: "val3",
  Text: "text3"
}, {
  Value: "val4",
  Text: "text4"
}]
```

I tried to add it using the method described in this answer: [Adding items to a Kendo multiSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065935/adding-items-to-a-kendo-multiselect)

I modified the code to the following:

```
var multiSelect = $("#mySelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");

// Read original data content
var multiData = multiSelect.dataSource.data();
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  // insert new element into copy of multiselect data
  multiData.push({
    text: response[i].Text,
    value: response[i].Value
  })
}
// Write back the modified data
multiSelect.dataSource.data(multiData);
```

However, all the new options added this way display as `undefined`. I've `console.log`'d `response` to verify that it has data in there.

I also can't find anything in the multiselect API like a `clear()` or `removeAll`. Just a `remove` that requires you to get each `dataItem` first before removing. Am I missing a better way?

Comment: What about [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iHoDU/2)

Comment: @bigless No, it behaves the same. It doesn't clear the existing options and the new options appended to the list are all undefined.

Comment: So you are not trying to change items but whole options.. Or merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear options, use

```
multiSelect.dataSource.data([]);
```

Check The demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
          
            $("#btn").click(function() {
              var multiSelect = $("#required").data("kendoMultiSelect");
              var response = [ { Text: "ship 1", Value: "Value1" },{ Text: "ship 2", Value: "Value2" }, { Text: "ship 3", Value: "Value3" },   { Text: "ship 4", Value: "Value4" } ];

              // clear previous data
               multiSelect.dataSource.data([]);
               
              var multiData = []; //multiSelect.dataSource.data();
              for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                // insert new element into copy of multiselect data
                multiData.push({
                  text: response[i].Text,
                  value: response[i].Value
                })
              }
              // Write back the modified data
              multiSelect.dataSource.data(multiData);

            });
        });
```

```css
.demo-section label {
            display: block;
            margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
        }
        #get {
            float: right;
            margin: 25px auto 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="example" role="application">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Kendo - Multiselect - Append to dataSource</h2>
        <label for="required">Required</label>
        <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>ABC</option>
            <option>XYZ</option>
            <option>PQR</option>
        </select>
        
        <button class="k-button" id="btn">GET Ajax data</button>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works (almost). Only change I had to make was to this line:                 `multiData.push({ Text: response[i].Text, Value: response[i].Value });` I had to capitalize `Text:` and `Value:` otherwise it just populated with `undefined undefined`